# How to see what a view is doing with Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

There is a View on my database. Is there a way with Management Studio to see what table and columns that view is connected to? The properties screen has no info on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the View and select "Design", or "Script View As > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window"